# Как десериализовать такой JSON (в Visual Studio)?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, сериализация

Есть такой JSON (так-то он длиннее):

```
{
    "result": [
        [
            9069250,
            "2018-07-05 23:22:33",
            "2018-07-20 12:33:26"
        ],
        [
            501184,
            "2018-07-07 07:25:57",
            "2018-07-20 12:33:31"
        ],
        [
            9117,
            "2018-07-07 21:11:30",
            "2018-07-20 12:42:57"
        ],
        [
            10539675,
            "2018-07-07 21:17:14",
            "2018-07-19 10:17:25"
        ]
   ]
}
```

Пытаюсь его десериализовать, но безуспешно... Не знаю как описать класс для такого json(a), потому что обычно пишут "атрибут:значение", а здесь просто каждый элемент это 3 перечисленных значения и вот как это всё мне по переменным раскидать...

Пробовал такой класс:

```
class JSON
{
   public result[] result { get; set; }
}
class result
{
   public string domain_id { get; set; }
   public string start { get; set; }
   public string stop { get; set; }
}
```

Но не получилось...

Код, который использую для сериализации:

```
StreamReader re = new StreamReader("JSON.json");
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(re);
JsonSerializer se = new JsonSerializer();
var DeserializedObject = se.Deserialize<JSON>(reader);
```

При запуске, у меня вышла ошибка:

```
"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ConsoleApp1.Program+result' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path 'result[0]', line 3, position 9."
```

Решить которую так и не удалось...

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю сначала разобрать в массив массивов строк

```
public class Data
{
    public List<List<string>> Result;
}

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(youJson);
```

Далее способ подходит в случае если ты 100% уверен, что порядок строк не поменяется. Создаем атрибут, который поможет нам упорядочить порядок пропертей в классе для извлечения их через рефлексию.

```
public class IndexAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Order { get; }
    public IndexAttribute(int order)
    {
        Order = order;
    }
}
```

Далее сам класс с нужными пропертями и уже навешанными атрибутами. Где цифра это их порядок в десереализуемом массиве.

```
public class Info
{
    [Index(0)]
    [JsonProperty("domain_id")]
    public string DomainId { get; set; }
    [Index(1)]
    public string Start { get; set; }
    [Index(2)]
    public string Stop { get; set; }
}
```

Ну и сам код разбора в объект. Код на неискушенный взгляд может показаться сложным и не избыточным, но мне нравятся LINQ. Можно было бы и через обычные for это сделать.

```
var infoProps = typeof(Info).GetProperties().OrderBy(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<IndexAttribute>().Order).ToList();
var result = b.Result.Select(rawInfo => infoProps.Zip(rawInfo, (prop, s) => new {prop, s}).Aggregate(new Info(),
            (instance, pair) =>
            {
                pair.prop.SetValue(instance, pair.s);
                return instance;
            })).ToList();
```

Суть проста. Сначала через рефлексию достаю все проперти и сортирую их по убыванию. 
Далее для каждого элемента массива "result" склеиваю их в пары (проперти - значение) и через метод Aggregate создаю экземпляры класса `Info` и в нем же заполняю все его свойства.

---

Такой способ бывает необходимо, когда нужно разобрать данные в упорядоченном виде без наименования поля.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается в студии есть встроенный инструмент для перевода json в классы: `Edit -> Paste special -> Paste JSON as classes`, который решил все мои проблемы

Comment: "Все проблемы"? Именно как раз на ассоциативных массивах, про которые вы задали вопрос этот инструмент даёт некачественный код.